# Spark task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception, serialization, serializable

I've tried all the solutions to this problem that I found on StackOverflow but, despite this, I can't solve it.
I have a "MainObj" object that instantiates a "Recommendation" object. When I call the "recommendationProducts" method I always get an error.
Here is the code of the method:

```
def recommendationProducts(item: Int): Unit = {

val aMatrix = new DoubleMatrix(Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))

def cosineSimilarity(vec1: DoubleMatrix, vec2: DoubleMatrix): Double = {
  vec1.dot(vec2) / (vec1.norm2() * vec2.norm2())
}

val itemFactor = model.productFeatures.lookup(item).head
val itemVector = new DoubleMatrix(itemFactor)

//Here is where I get the error:
val sims = model.productFeatures.map { case (id, factor) =>
  val factorVector = new DoubleMatrix(factor)
  val sim = cosineSimilarity(factorVector, itemVector)
  (id, sim)
}

val sortedSims = sims.top(10)(Ordering.by[(Int, Double), Double] {
  case (id, similarity) => similarity
})

println("\nTop 10 products:")
sortedSims.map(x => (x._1, x._2)).foreach(println)
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
at RecommendationObj.recommendationProducts(RecommendationObj.scala:269)
at MainObj$.analisiIUNGO(MainObj.scala:257)
at MainObj$.menu(MainObj.scala:54)
at MainObj$.main(MainObj.scala:37)
at MainObj.main(MainObj.scala)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@7c2312fa)
- field (class: RecommendationObj, name: sc, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
- object (class MainObj$$anon$1, MainObj$$anon$1@615bad16)
- field (class: RecommendationObj$$anonfun$37, name: $outer, type: class RecommendationObj)
- object (class RecommendationObj$$anonfun$37, <function1>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
... 14 more
```

I tried to add:
1) "extends Serializable" (Scala) to my Class
2) "extends extends java.io.Serializable" to my Class
3) "@transient" to some parts
4) Get the model (and other features) inside this class (Now I get them from an other object and I pass them to my Class like arguments)

How can I resolve it? I'm becoming crazy!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Key is here:

```
 field (class: RecommendationObj, name: sc, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
```

So you have field named sc of type SparkContext. Spark wants to serialize the class, so he try also to serialize all fields.

You should:

- use @transient annotation and checking if null, then recreate
- not use SparkContext from field, but put it into argument of method. However remember, that you never should use SparkContext inside closures in map, flatMap, etc.

Comment: Thank you! It works! However I pass SparkContext (sc) like argument of the Class and I use it to load the model in the constructor. Is it wrong?

Comment: @S.SP If it helped you, please up vote and accept the answer. It's not wrong, but then you must use the `@transient ` annotation to say serializer to not serialize it

Comment: Ok! Thank you. I want to up vote you but I still not have the 15 reputation points to do it. I'm sorry because your answer helped me so much !

Comment: @S.SP Thank you :)